# How to update cluster and node version explicitly in gke using terraform

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating gke cluster using terraform my requirement to provide cluster and node version explicitly. I am using data source to get those version tried many option not able to provide cluster and node version

Data block

```
data "google_container_engine_versions" "gke_version" {
  location       = us-central1-a
  version_prefix = "1.25."
}
```

Cluster creation resource block

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "gke" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  location = var.cluster_location
  networking_mode = var.networking_mode
  network         = var.network
  subnetwork      = var.subnetwork
  remove_default_node_pool = var.remove_default_node_pool
  initial_node_count       = var.initial_node_count 
  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = var.cluster_secondary_range_name
    services_secondary_range_name = var.services_secondary_range_name
  }
}
```

Node creation resource block

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "permanent" {
  name       = var.permanent_pool_name
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.gke.id
  node_count = var.permanent_node_count
  management {
    auto_repair  = var.auto_repair
    auto_upgrade = var.auto_upgrade
  }
  node_config {
    preemptible = var.permanent_preemptible
    machine_type = var.permanent_machine_type
    disk_size_gb = var.permanent_disk_size_gb
    disk_type = var.gke_disk_type
    labels = {
      type = var.permanent_labels
    }
    
    service_account = var.svc_account
    oauth_scopes = [var.oauth_scopes]
  }
}
```

How can I provide cluster and node version on these respective resource block ?

Comment: Did the example usage not work? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/container_engine_versions#example-usage

Comment: yes giving below error In my case I need to delete default node pools  │ Error: 1 error occurred: 
│       * node_version can only be specified if remove_default_node_pool is not true
│   with google_container_cluster.gke,
│   on main.tf line 6, in resource "google_container_cluster" "gke":
│    6: resource "google_container_cluster" "gke" {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a cluster and nodepool with the latest 1.25.x version if you make these changes:

Cluster creation resource block

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "gke" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  location = var.cluster_location
  networking_mode    = var.networking_mode
  network            = var.network
  subnetwork         = var.subnetwork
  initial_node_count = var.initial_node_count

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = var.cluster_secondary_range_name
    services_secondary_range_name = var.services_secondary_range_name
  }

  // changed:
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  min_master_version       = data.google_container_engine_versions.gke_version.latest_master_version
  release_channel {
    channel = "UNSPECIFIED"
  }
}
```

Node creation resource block

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "permanent" {
  name       = var.permanent_pool_name
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.gke.id
  node_count = var.permanent_node_count
  
  node_config {
    preemptible = var.permanent_preemptible
    machine_type = var.permanent_machine_type
    disk_size_gb = var.permanent_disk_size_gb
    disk_type = var.gke_disk_type
    labels = {
      type = var.permanent_labels
    }
    
    service_account = var.svc_account
    oauth_scopes = [var.oauth_scopes]
  }


  //changed:
  management {
    auto_repair  = var.auto_repair
    auto_upgrade = false
  }
  version = data.google_container_engine_versions.gke_version.latest_node_version
}
```